# java boolean field save as false need to be save as true

Tags: java, hibernate, boolean

Am having a field called `legal_hold` in my `User` model class and from my controller am trying to save User object into the User table by default i want to save the `legal_hold` as true. The datatype of the `legal_hold` field is boolean.

Please see my below code. But `legal_hold` field is not saving as `true` in table. Its saving as `false`.

could anyone suggest on this.?

Following is my controller class

UserController.java

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User newUser) {
  System.out.println("New User -->"+newUser.isLegalHold())
  User user = userService.createUser(newUser);
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setLocation(new UserResource(user).selfUri());
 return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Following is my model class
User.java

```
@Column(name = "legal_hold")
private boolean legalHold = true;
```

Comment: *"Am having a field called `hold` in my `User` model class"* Wrong! You have a field named `Hold`. Java identifiers are **case-sensitive**, so `hold` and `Hold` are two entirely different names.

Comment: @Andreas - actually `legal_hold` is my column name and am using variable name as `legalHold` still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this definition on your entity class

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
@Column(name = "legal_hold")
private boolean legalHold;
```